# How to report eth-harvest.com as a SCAM

Tags: fraud

I originally suspected this website was to good to be true but now it has been officially confirmed. How can I begin the campaign to warn others that this site is a scam and work to get is shut down?

Comment: If it has been officially confirmed as a scam, then there is nothing you need to do?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a source online saying it is a scam, and with PROOF, then, there is not much you can do then try and get others over to the article/video for them to see it is a scam.

If the scam has a forum on it, make as many posts as possible detailing it as a scam, and putting links to a article that has proof of it being a scam. This will hopefully bring many users to their senses, and save them from using hard earned money

Hope this helped!